# How can you use npx create-react-app with templates in a private registry?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I'm trying to use `npx create-react-app` with a `--template` from a private NPM registry, for example:

```
npx create-react-app example-app --template @private/mytemplate
```

I've added a `.npmrc` file to the root directory that points to the private registry. I've ensured this is setup correctly because I'm able to install private NPM packages without any problems.

However, when I run thecommand it defaults back to the normal NPM registry and I receive an error that my private template package doesn't exist:

```
404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@private/mytemplate
```

If I update the NPM registry manually through `npm config set registry [my registry]` then I receive an error that `create-react-app` doesn't exist.

Is there a way to use `create-react-app` from the public registry and point to a template stored in my private registry in a single command? Or in other words, how can you use `npx create-react-app` with templates stored in a private registry?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. Instead of changing my registry with `npm config set registry [my registry]` I just needed to alias the registry for my specific private packages.

This was done by running:

```
npm config set @mypackagename:registry [my registry]
```

The `@mypackagename:registry` was the key point of confusion where "registry" is the actual value and not a placeholder.